# Poner comentarios en archivo JSON en Visual Studio 2015

Tags: json, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Estoy experimentando con el nuevo `Visual Studio` y veo que en la nueva estructura de proyecto y en la configuración se hace uso intensivo de los archivos `JSON`, en detrimento del `XML` que se usaba antes en el `web.config`, etc.

El caso es que me gustaría dejar comentadas algunas dependencias en el archivo `config.json` y me encuentro con que, usando `//` para comentar una linea, el coloreador de sintaxis actua correctamente, pero el compilador no se lo traga.

¿Existe alguna sintaxis especial para este tipo de comentarios al menos en los archivos de configuración?

Comment: He quitado las etiquetas de ASP.NET porque el problema es exclusivo del formato JSON, independientemente del entorno en el que se usa.

Comment: El formato JSON no admite comentarios, eso está claro... La duda es si Visual Studio 2015 los admite en los ficheros JSON, porque podría eliminarlos antes de procesarlos o tener alguna sintaxis especial, como ha hecho Microsoft un millon de veces con lo estandar. Así que @Konamiman, las etiquetas estaban bien...

Comment: Visto así tienes razón. He añadido las etiquetas apropiadas, aunque no son las mismas que había originalmente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El coloreador de sintaxis lo marca, pero al hacer build claramente detecta el error (ver imagen más abajo).

Mi recomendación en este caso particular, donde quieres **deshabilitar la dependencia temporalmente**, es crear una nueva sección en el archivo de configuración, ejemplo acá estoy moviendo a esta sección la referencia de Azure Storage, cuando quiera volverla poner la muevo a la sección correcta.

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
},
"commentedDependencies": {
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "6.1.0"
},
```

Esto evita cambiar el nombre de la dependencia , porque entonces el motor buscará una dependencia que no se resolverá y se puede dar para otros errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que JSON no es JavaScript (véanse [www.json.org](http://www.json.org/), [rfc4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), [rfc7159](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt) y la sugerencia siguiente) y por tanto no es reconocido al momento de parsearlo.

Lo solución típica sugerida ([véase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-i-use-comments-inside-a-json-file)) suele ser añadir una propiedad tipo comentario como:

```
"__comment": "bla, bla, ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes especificar varios valores con la misma clave pero la última tiene prioridad sobre la anterior, sabiendo esto puedes usar lo siguiente pero no sé si esto será la mejor forma, pero quizás te sirva.

```
{
  "numeros": "esto es un comentario",
  "numeros": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es inhabilitar una cierta clave de un fichero de configuración sin borrarla, simplemente cámbiale el nombre; el motor ignorará cualquier clave desconocida (y es de suponer que tu código también lo hará, si usas ficheros de configuración personalizados). Una buena convención es, como sugiere josejuan, añadir un subrayado ("_") al principio del nombre; de esta forma se ve de un vistazo qué claves están "comentadas".